# How to reduce android permissions?

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

I am developing an app and I really do not use the permissions required when installing from the Google Play. when the user see those permissions get frustrated and may not install the app.

[image: permissions on the market]

I use push notification, access to calendar with those permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Is there any way to better view those permissions so the users will not get shocked? Also why the app has access to photos/media/files?
Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why these negatives even I got an answer from CommonsWare which means a valid question that has a valid answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to better view those permissions so the users will not get shocked?

Remove the permissions that you do not want, and remove the features from your app that depend upon those permissions.

However, most of what is showing up in that dialog is not coming from your app's list of `<uses-permission>` elements.

> Also why the app has access to photos/media/files?

Because you are depending upon Google Play Services, and [it adds `<uses-permission>` elements to your manifest](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html).

Look at the "Selectively compiling APIs into your executable" section in [the Play Services setup documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) and see if you can use finer-grained dependencies that can reduce the number of permissions that Play Services requests in your app.